# I need to put the follwing blocks of code in the same row using visual studio

Tags: row, codeblocks

They all need to be seperate but all need to be lined up in a row

```
<h5 style="display: inline-block;font-size:125%; text-align: center; color: #230d61;">General Ledger</h5>
<br style="font-size: 125%;text-align: center;">Bank Reconciliation<br>Month End Closings<br>Financial Statements
```

Accounts Recievable
    Progress Billing
Unitary Billing
T&M Billing

Accounts Payable
    Insurance Compliance Management
Credit Card Management
1099's

I have tried many ways but am unable to solve this